# speeding up sequential checking if a point is in a shape in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, geometry, vectorization

I have a code for sequentially whether every pair of cartesian coordinates found in my `DataFrame` fall into certain geometric enclosed areas. But it is rather slow, I suspect because it is not vectorized. Here is an example:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

r1 = Rectangle((0,0), 10, 10)
r2 = Rectangle((50,50), 10, 10)

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[-1,5], [51,52]], columns=['x', 'y'])

for j in range(df.shape[0]):
    coordinates = df.x.iloc[j], df.y.iloc[j]
    if r1.contains_point(coordinates):
        df['location'].iloc[j] = 0
    else r2.contains_point(coordinates):
        df['location'].iloc[j] = 1
```

Can someone propose an approach for speed-up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to convert the rectangular patches into an array and work on it after deducing the extent to which they are spread out.

```
def seqcheck_vect(df):
    xy = df[["x", "y"]].values
    e1 = np.asarray(rec1.get_extents())
    e2 = np.asarray(rec2.get_extents())
    r1m1, r1m2 = np.min(e1), np.max(e1)
    r2m1, r2m2 = np.min(e2), np.max(e2)
    out = np.where(((xy >= r1m1) & (xy <= r1m2)).all(axis=1), 0, 
                   np.where(((xy >= r2m1) & (xy <= r2m2)).all(axis=1), 1, np.nan))
    return df.assign(location=out)
```

For the given sample the function outputs:

[image]

---

***benchmarks:***

```
def loopy_version(df):
    for j in range(df.shape[0]):
        coordinates = df.x.iloc[j], df.y.iloc[j]
        if rec1.contains_point(coordinates):
            df.loc[j, "location"] = 0
        elif rec2.contains_point(coordinates):
            df.loc[j, "location"] = 1
        else:
            pass
    return df
```

***testing on a `DF` of 10K rows:***

```
np.random.seed(42)
df  = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, (10000,2)), columns=list("xy"))

# check if both give same outcome
loopy_version(df).equals(seqcheck_vect(df))
True

%timeit loopy_version(df)
1 loop, best of 3: 3.8 s per loop

%timeit seqcheck_vect(df)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.73 ms per loop
```

So, the vectorized approach is approximately 2200 times faster compared to the loopy one.

Comment: Thank you. I am wondering though, is there a more general method that does not rely on it being a rectangle, but is vectorized? Your approach did rely on it if I am not wrong

Comment: Basically any structure which has a range to compare against the values present in the `DF` would follow a similar implementation as shown above. There should be a way in which you can extract the starting and ending points out of them and store the result in an array.

Comment: Besides, all patches do have a `.get_extents()` method, so that should pose no problem I guess.