# Python: Check if points are in a sphere

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following problem. I have a dataset of three dimensional coordinates, of which each is the center of a cell/sphere. Now i have to check if points in a three dimensional grid, which all have a value of zero, are neighbors of this sphere and if so they get a value +1. The trhee dimensional grid has the dimensions of the maximum of x,y,z from the coordinates. My first idea was to create sphere objects with vtk for python out of the coordinate list. Furthermore I created a numpy array of zeros with 3 dimensions. Now i could check every point of the grid if it is inside of the spheres, and if not and it is the neighbor of the sphere, it gets +1.

To check all coordiantes of the grid if there are in a sphere with center (x,y,z) with for-loops would be too time expensive (N^3). Is there a easy way to get the the neighbor coordinates from the sphere in the 3D grid or to check if they are in sphere or not in sphere?

I saw that matplotlib has the functions "contains_points". In another thread there was an example:

```
>>> from matplotlib import path
>>> p = path.Path([(0,0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)])  # square with legs     length 1 and bottom left corner at the origin
>>> p.contains_points([(.5, .5)])
array([ True], dtype=bool)
```

Of course, we could use a numpy array of points as well:

```
>>> points = np.array([.5, .5]).reshape(1, 2)
>>> points
array([[ 0.5,  0.5]])
>>> p.contains_points(points)
array([ True], dtype=bool)
```

Is it possible to do this for 3 dimensions, or another possibility to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [speeding up sequential checking if a point is in a shape in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42944841/speeding-up-sequential-checking-if-a-point-is-in-a-shape-in-python)

Comment: Do I understand this right: you want to know for each point on a grid how many "spheres" are within a given radius to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood your question properly, I would recommend simply iterating over your spheres and determining what integer coordinates fall within the radius. The easiest way (not necessarily the best) would be to find the coordinates within a bounding box and then filter by euclidean distance. If your coordinate space is very large, a sparse matrix will help reduce memory usage.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import itertools

spheres = np.random.rand(10,3) * 100 #ten random points in 3-space from 0 - 100
radius = 2 #spheres have radius 2

sparse = {} #use a dictionary with tuple keys as a sparse 3d matrix

for sphere in spheres:
    #outer bounding box
    x0 = math.floor(sphere[0]-radius)
    x1 = math.ceil(sphere[0]+radius)
    y0 = math.floor(sphere[1]-radius)
    y1 = math.ceil(sphere[1]+radius)
    z0 = math.floor(sphere[2]-radius)
    z1 = math.ceil(sphere[2]+radius)
    #add 1 to upper bounds to range is inclusive
    for coords in itertools.product(range(x0,x1+1), range(y0,y1+1), range(z0,z1+1)):
        if radius**2 >= sum((sphere - coords)**2): #euclidean distance is smaller than radius
            value = sparse.get(coords, 0) + 1
            sparse[coords] = value
```

Depending on the size of your 3d grid and the radius of your spheres, this improves upon calculating the distance to every point from every sphere by only considering first the square bounding box aligned on the grid. As the radius increases, this will approach roughly 50% efficiency with respect to how many distances are calculated that end up falling outside each sphere.

#### Edit:

As per your comments I have changed my approach a little bit..

Wanting to find all points surrounding the sphere but not in it leads me to a slightly different approach. The first part is effectively the same, but instead of writing the result directly to our sparse array, we will use a dense array of the region. Then we can use convolution to find edges of the filled region (google "edge filter convolution" for more reading). This filter could be altered to include or exclude diagonals, but in this example I have included them. Technically the algorithmic complexity is greater, because Convolution is O(n<sup>k</sup>) complexity for a k dimensional array (in this case O(n<sup>3</sup>)), but scipy implements this function efficiently in compiled c instead of pure python. Finally, we loop over our region where we've found the edges and add them to the sparse array.

```
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.ndimage.filters import convolve

spheres = np.random.rand(8,3) * 10 #ten random points in 3-space from 0 - 100
radius = 3 #spheres have radius 2

sparse = {} #use a dictionary with tuple keys as a sparse 3d matrix

kernel = np.ones([3,3,3]) #ones will multiply with non-zero elements of spherical region
kernel[1,1,1] = -30 #value will be pulled negative if spherical region intersects center "pixel"
for sphere in spheres:
    x0 = math.floor(sphere[0]-radius)
    x1 = math.ceil(sphere[0]+radius)
    y0 = math.floor(sphere[1]-radius)
    y1 = math.ceil(sphere[1]+radius)
    z0 = math.floor(sphere[2]-radius)
    z1 = math.ceil(sphere[2]+radius)
    region = np.zeros([x1-x0+1, y1-y0+1, z1-z0+1])
    for index, x in np.ndenumerate(region):
        #align new axes
        coords = np.array([x0, y0, z0]) + index
        if radius**2 >= sum((sphere - coords)**2): #euclidean distance is smaller than radius
            region[index] = 1
    edge = convolve(region, kernel, mode='constant', cval=0.0) > 0 #convolve and test if greater than 0
    for index, x in np.ndenumerate(edge):
        if edge:
            value = sparse.get((index[0]+x0, index[1]+y0, index[2]+z0), 0)
            sparse[(index[0]+x0, index[1]+y0, index[2]+z0)] = value + 1
```

Comment: Nice, thank you:) But what is the second key entry in the ditctionary for the sparse matrix for? And if i understand the code right, your idea is to iterate along all points within a bounding box and to increase the value of one by 1 if it is in the sphere. But i want only to increase it if it is not in sphere, BUT a direct neighbor of it.

Comment: Are you referring to my usage of `sparse.get()`? This basically allows me to provide a default value to `sparse[coords]` in case it does not exist yet. As for increasing only neighbors.. I'm not sure I'm clear on how you want to define which points to increment. Is it any point on the grid not inside the sphere but at most one grid spacing away? Does this include diagonals along the grid?

Comment: Yes, it should be one grid space away and also include diagonals:)

Comment: Nice thank you, I had another idea, but i do not know how realize it: Wouldnt it be more efficient to calculate all surface coordinates of a sphere with radius +1 and only to store those coordinates, which have integer coordiantes?

Comment: @Varlor that would not account for diagonals with just +1. I'm not going to go through the proof to determine if it's possible to get the same result with a simple radius offset.. It may be possible

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you calculate if the radial distance of a given point is <= of the radial distance of one of the "last" points of the sphere? If True, it is comprised. It's O(n)